# Using VMenu from vuetify with render function (scoped slot)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to use Vuetify's `VMenu` component and I would like that when a user clicks the button the `VMenu` shows up. As far as the [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus/#close-on-click) goes it says we should add a scoped slot. Doing with a normal template it works but when I switch to a render function approach it never renders the button.

I have been following the Vue's [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Slots) and ended up with:

```
h(VMenu, { props: { value: isMenuOpen.value } }, [
            h(
              "template",
              {
                scopedSlots: {
                  activator: ({ on, attrs }) => {
                     debugger; // it never reaches this debugger
                     return h(VButton, { on, attrs }, 'click me');
                  }
                },
              },
              []
            ),
            h(VList, [h(VListItem, [h(VListItemTitle, ["Logout"])])]),
          ]),
```

I have tried using a non-arrow function as well:

```
scopedSlots: { activator: function({ on, attrs }) {  return h('div', 'click me');  } }
```

and return a simple `h('div', 'click me')` in both non-arrow function and arrow function and nothing seems to work.

How can I pass the scoped slot `activator` to `VMenu` component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scoped slots are passed through the [`scopedSlots` property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#createElement-Arguments) of `createElement`'s 2nd argument in the form of `{ name: props => VNode | Array<VNode> }`. In your case, `scopedSlots` should have two entries: one for `activator`, and another for `default`:

```js
import { VMenu, VList, VListItem, VBtn } from 'vuetify/lib'

export default {
  render(h) {
    return h(VMenu, {
      scopedSlots: {
        activator: props => h(VBtn, props, 'Open'),
        default: () => h(VList, [
          h(VListItem, 'item 1'),
          h(VListItem, 'item 2'),
          h(VListItem, 'item 3'),
        ]),
      },
    })
  }
}
```

which is equivalent to this template:

```html
<template>
  <v-menu>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
      <v-btn v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">Open</v-btn>
    </template>
    <v-list>
      <v-list-item>item 1</v-list-item>
      <v-list-item>item 2</v-list-item>
      <v-list-item>item 3</v-list-item>
    </v-list>
  </v-menu>
</template>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vmenu-in-render-function-wz1tm?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: Once again you have helped me @tony19. Thank you very much.

Comment: +1 I was under the impression you were supposed to do `[ h('template', ...) ]` (for the children array) but actually it only works if you don't

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to fully understand the problem described in my question. This is an answer not to answer the fully original question but to guide future users that may come to this question.

Instead of using a scoped slot I have used the `value` prop in combination with `attach` prop. This solution in the end ended up working without no problem.

```
button(
            {
              attrs: { "data-account-setting": true },
              props: { plain: true, rounded: true, icon: true },
              on: { click: onOpenMenuClick },
            },
            [h(VIcon, ["mdi-account-outline"])]
          ),
          h(
            VMenu,
            {
              props: {
                value: isMenuOpen.value,
                // waiting on answer on SO
                // @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67405594/using-vmenu-from-vuetify-with-render-function-scoped-slot
                attach: "[data-account-setting]",
                minWidth: "300px",
                left: true,
                offsetY: true,
                closeOnContentClick: false,
                rounded: true,
              },
              on: {
                input: (value: boolean) => {
                  isMenuOpen.value = value;
                },
              },
            },
            [
              h(VList, { props: { dense: true } }, [
                h(VListItem, { props: { to: { name: "logout" } } }, [
                  h(VListItemTitle, { attrs: { 'data-cy-logout': true } }, ["Logout"]),
                ]),
              ]),
            ]
          ),
```