# Using VAutocomplete from vuetify with render function (scoped slot)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Am trying to use the Autocomplete component inside a render function. When I try to use the **scopedSlots** of the component it won't work for me. My code:

```js
  import { VAutocomplete } from 'vuetify/lib'

  export default {
    render (h) {
      return h(VAutocomplete, {
        scopedSlots: {
          label: () => h('h1', 'lol'),
          'append-item': () => h('p', 'Last item')
        },
      })
    },
  }
```

I tried using the answer on this post [Vuetify VMenu with render function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67405594/using-vmenu-from-vuetify-with-render-function-scoped-slot)

The answer when I try it works however when I apply it to the Autocomplete it isn't working for me in the slots I have tried. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`label` isn't a scoped slot, you have to do:

```js
h(VAutocomplete, [
  h('h1', { slot: 'label' }, 'lol')
])
```

Comment: Label is a prop but is also a scoped slot. I used it in my example code because I wanted to make it as simple as possible.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-autocomplete/#slots

Comment: It is not a scoped slot (trust me, I wrote it). In templates there is now no difference between scoped or not but render functions still have to use `slot` for non-scoped slots.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why non-scoped slots? I don't get it